# Why are "if "and "while" not interchangeable in my python-3.x code below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=1
b=a+1
c=a+b
x=0 

while c < 5:
    c=c+1
    x=x+1
if c == 5:
    print ("\n It took this many loops to make C=5: ",x)
```

The above code works as I want but, I need the below code to work. I'm suppose to use If/Else functions but, can only get the While function to run for me.

```
if c < 5:
    c=c+1
    x=x+1
if c == 5:
    print ("\n It took this many loops to make C=5: ",x)
```

I've tried several different ways but would appreciate any helpful explanation on why it doesn't run.

Comment: I recommend [A Byte of Python](https://python.swaroopch.com/) for beginners.

Comment: I'm terrible at learning by reading, thanks for the reference though.

Comment: Using an `if` does "work" in the sense that the code compiles fine and runs. But if the body of the `while` loop is only run once (by the `if`), you won't meet the condition for the second loop, so it won't print anything. It's not obvious why you would want to use an `if` instead of the `while`, so I'm not sure there's a reasonable way to fix the "problem". You can't count loops if there are no loops after all.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `if`, `else`, `while`s are NOT functions. They are **statements** (more precisely, flow control statements).

The core difference is that `if` runs the indented code block **once** when the condition is satisfied (evaluates to `True`), whereas `while` runs the code block repeatedly **as long as** the condition remains satisfied.

An `if` block will pass after running once, no matter whether the condition is still satisfied. A `while` block will go back and repeat if the condition is still satisfied at the end of one loop.